# Swift, SpriteKit - Pause whole script

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, pause

Is it possible to pause the whole script in GameScene using code from the GameViewController? I do not want to delay/pause the thread. There are multiple activities and functions going on at the same time and I would like to pause everything.

I would also like to be able to resume after having paused.

For example, in the GameViewController:

```
GameScene.pause()
```

and

```
GameScene.resume()
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Pausing within the GameScene**

Pausing the scene:

`self.paused = true` (`self` is the `GameScene`).

Pausing the view (`SKView`):

```
self.view?.paused = true
```

**Pausing within the GameViewController**

Pausing the scene:

```
let skView = self.view as! SKView
skView.scene?.paused = true
```

Pausing the view (`SKView`):

```
let skView = self.view as! SKView
skView.paused = true
```

To unpause just set `paused` property to `false`.